# Creating a working form in ExpressJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express

I am new to NodeJS and ExpressJS development (a week old or so). I am trying to create a web application in NodeJS using ExpressJS framework. One of the things I am trying to do is build a registration form for my app. I have installed body-parser middleware using the npm to read form data.

I am using HoganJS as my template framework. I have a page in my views folder named register.hjs. This page has a form

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="name">
    <input type="text" name="age">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

I am struggling with these two issues:

1. How to read form values in the .js
2. How to redirect a user to a different page once form is submitted.

This is what I am trying to do (it might be incorrect though).

In my app.js

```
//get
app.get('/register', routes.register);

//post
app.post('/welcome', routes.welcome);
```

In my index.js

```
 /* GET about page.*/
 exports.register = function(req, res) {
   res.render('register');
  };

/*POST registered user*/

exports.welcome = function(req, res) {

// pull the form variables off the request body
var name = req.body.name;
var age = req.body.age;

//just to make sure the information was read
console.log(name);
console.log(age);

res.render('welcome');

};
```

I am pretty sure I am missing something cause when I run my server it gives an error saying :

Error: Route.get() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]

What am I doing wrong? Is there any elegant way to read form data and redirect users to different pages?

Thanks.

--------------------------- Update ----------------------------

Here is the rest of the app.js Code

```
   var express = require('express');
   var path = require('path');
   var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
   var logger = require('morgan');
   var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
   var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

  //routes to the pages
  var routes = require('./routes/index');
  var users = require('./routes/users');
  var register = require('./routes/register');

  var app = express();

 // view engine setup
 app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')); //app.set('the name of your    view folder', )
 app.set('view engine', 'hjs');

//get
app.get('/register', routes.register);

//post
app.post('/welcome', routes.welcome);

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);
app.use('/register', register);

//error handlers 
//error handlers

 module.exports = app;
```

Comment: can i see the rest of app.js code?

Comment: how are u calling routes in app.js?

Comment: this is a problem related with routes.

Comment: app.get('/register', routes.registe); <- there is a typo here.. in your code is like that, or you copy and past wrong here?

Comment: i pasted wrong there.

Answer (score 2):

For Simple understanding how express works for form understand this code :
After understanding this code , use router and other body parser configuration---

```
var express = require('express');

/*
 * body-parser is a piece of express middleware that 
 *   reads a form's input and stores it as a javascript
 *   object accessible through `req.body` 
 *
 * 'body-parser' must be installed (via `npm install --save body-parser`)
 * For more info see: https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser
 */
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// create our app
var app = express();

// instruct the app to use the `bodyParser()` middleware for all routes
app.use(bodyParser());

// A browser's default method is 'GET', so this
// is the route that express uses when we visit
// our site initially.
app.get('/', function(req, res){
  // The form's action is '/' and its method is 'POST',
  // so the `app.post('/', ...` route will receive the
  // result of our form
  var html = '<form action="/" method="post">' +
               'Enter your name:' +
               '<input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="..." />' +
               '<br>' +
               '<button type="submit">Submit</button>' +
            '</form>';

  res.send(html);
});

// This route receives the posted form.
// As explained above, usage of 'body-parser' means
// that `req.body` will be filled in with the form elements
app.post('/', function(req, res){
  var userName = req.body.userName;
  var html = 'Hello: ' + userName + '.<br>' +
             '<a href="/">Try again.</a>';
  res.send(html);
});

app.listen(80);
```

Answer (score 0):

app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hjs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);

module.exports = app;
```

index.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/register', function(req, res) {
  res.render('register');
});

router.post('/welcome', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body.name);
    console.log(req.body.age);
});



module.exports = router;
```

Comment: in the register route?

Comment: yes, when i enter name and age and hit submit, it gives me 404.

Comment: of course.. you can GET a post route, for access the values with a router.post you need create an ajax POST. If you want GET, just change router.post to router.get.

Comment: so i added app.post('/welcome', function(req, res){ }); in my app.js but it still gives me 404 not found.

Comment: you CANT access a POST router, only GET.

Comment: POST routes are made to send data, not to access.